# Paths for images using Apache with Windows

Tags: php, apache, path, src

I have a problem with links testing locally using Apache with Windows. The final links have the following format:

```
file:///C:/Documents and Settings/USUARIO/My Documents/xampp/htdocs/my_website/images/january/my_image.jpg
```

The images do not show. However, if I directly copy the src from the img tag and paste it into the browser (Firefox), the image shows up.

*I generate the links using the following code:*

I define the images directory using: `define(IMAGE_DIR, dirname(__FILE__).'/images/');`
Then I use the following to format the path:

```
$imgPath = IMAGE_DIR.$month.$img;   
if($localServer)
{
   $imgPath = str_replace('/','\\', $imgPath);
   $imgPath = 'file:///'.$imgPath;
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating image sources that use `file://` URLs in a page that was loaded from a web server. File URLs instruct the browser to load a file directly from the disk without making a request to the web server. For security reasons, Firefox and other browsers don't allow pages served by a web server to reference local files, so don't show the images. People accessing your site remotely won't be able to access the files either because the image source would be a reference to a path on their computer.

To get the images to appear, you'll need to change your image sources to refer to locations on a web server, for example `images/january/my_image.jpg` or `/images/january/my_image.jpg`.

`images/january/my_image.jpg` will be interpreted by the web browser relative to the page being requested. For example, if the image appears on the page at `http://localhost/page1.php`, then the browser will request `http://localhost/images/january/my_image.jpg`. However, if the image is used on a page at `http://localhost/subdir/page1.php`, the browser will request `http://localhost/subdir/images/january/my_image.jpg` instead.

`/images/january/my_image.jpg` will always be interpreted relative to the root of the website. The web browser will request `http://localhost/images/january/my_image.jpg` for any page on `http://localhost`.

You can also use an absolute URL if you need to refer to an image on another web server, for example, `http://otherhost/images/january/my_image.jpg`.

Comment: I use dirname(__FILE__) to define the path so that when I include the config file using include() the paths do not change in different directories. If I use define(IMAGE_DIR, '/images/') won't I run into trouble when including that config file in different directories?

Comment: @sala_7 No you won't have any trouble with different directories. Regardless of the directory your page is in, a path starting with `/` will always refer to the same location on the web server.

Comment: Thanks a million! I think I was getting confused with paths from an includes folder below the web root that use include() to import page parts from other directories

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the constant "DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR" instead of '/' or '\'